# How many ways are there to arrange 4 letters from “combinatorics”?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways are there to arrange 4 letters from “combinatorics”?

So I’m studying about combinatorics and permutations. And I stuck with this question. So I just doing my own step but I want to make sure that it’s correct or not.

[image]

thank you very much and sorry about my bad grammar :)

Comment: Your `4` looks a bit weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your work is mostly fine.

However, for case $1$ (no letters the same), it should be $^{10}P_4 = \ ^{10}C_4 \cdot 4! = \ ^{10}C_\color{red}{6} \cdot 4!$. It would be better to write this number as a permutation, as which order you place the numbers matters.